# Argument for @NotNull parameter 'value' of jetbrains/buildServer/serverSide/impl/build/steps/BuildStartContextImpl.addSharedParameter must not be null

Tags: image

We have recently upgraded teamcity to vto 10.0.2 and post upgrade when I try to run a build I am getting below error.

> Argument for @NotNull parameter 'value' of
>   jetbrains/buildServer/serverSide/impl/build/steps/BuildStartContextImpl.addSharedParameter
>   must not be null

Really it helps if some one can help on this on priority.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by restarting the service TeamCity.

Comment: what was the root cause?

Comment: I can't remember now.